# colors text in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

How can I make in this fashion with same color of blue and white?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283349/create-horizontal-bar-with-embedded-text/283369#283369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\colorbox{blue!65!green!50!black}{%
  \color{white}\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep]{\bfseries PROFILE SUMMARY}}
\medskip

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]